# How to play songs with AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avaudioplayer, avqueueplayer

I can't seem to find understandable documentation or examples for `AVQueuePlayer`. I am currently trying to change my `AudioManager` so I can play an album with multiple or just a single song. I would appreciate any code examples or good articles about `AVQueuePlayer`.

Here is my code base for playing a single song:

```
final class AudioManager: ObservableObject {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false
    
    func startPlayer(track: String) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: track, withExtension: "mp3") else {return}
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.play()
            isPlaying = true
        } catch {
            print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
        }
    }
    
    func playPause() {
        guard let player = player else {
            print("Instance of audio player not found")
            return
        }
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.pause()
            isPlaying = false
        } else {
            player.play()
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        guard let player = player else {
            return
        }
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.stop()
            isPlaying = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is what I tried to do so far with my new `AudioQueueManager`class:

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

final class AudioQueueManager: ObservableObject {
    var player: AVQueuePlayer?
    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false
    @Published var someType: SomeType = .album(Album.data)
    
    func startPlayer(someType: SomeType) {
        switch someType {
        case .song(let song):
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: song.track, withExtension: "mp3")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                player = AVQueuePlayer(url: url!)
                player?.play()
                isPlaying = true
            } catch {
                print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
            }
        case .album(let album):
            var items: [AVPlayerItem] = []
            album.songs?.forEach({ albumsong in
                items.append(AVPlayerItem(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: albumsong.track, withExtension: "mp3")!))
            })
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                player = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
                player?.play()
                isPlaying = true
            } catch {
                print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func playPause() {
        guard let player = player else {
            print("Instance of audio player not found")
            return
        }
        if player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            player.pause()
            isPlaying = false
        } else {
            player.play()
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        guard let player = player else {
            return
        }
            player.removeAllItems()
            isPlaying = false
        
    }
    
}
```

Stopping/Starting a new song/album does not work, I cannot find the equivalent to `player.stop()`for `AVQueuePlayer`. Also trying to forward 10 seconds does not work as before: `audioManager.player?.currentTime += 10` I tried doing it like this
`audioQueueManager.player?.currentTime().value += 10` but value is not mutable and accessing currentTime is also not possible anymore since it expects CMTime instead of Int.

This is how I start my player in my View:

```
enum SomeType {
    case song(Song)
    case album(Album)
}
@EnvironmentObject var audioQueueManger: AudioQueueManager
switch type {
                case .song(let song):
//                    audioManager.stop()
//                    audioManager.isPlaying = true
//                    audioManager.startPlayer(track: song.track)
                    audioQueueManager.stop()
                    audioQueueManager.isPlaying = true
                    audioQueueManager.startPlayer(someType: .song(song))
                    
                    musicPlayerVm.addCurrentSong()
                case .album(let album):
//                    audioManager.stop()
//                    audioManager.isPlaying = true
//                    audioManager.startPlayer(track: album.songs?[0].track ?? "track1")
                    audioQueueManager.stop()
                    audioQueueManager.isPlaying = true
                    audioQueueManager.startPlayer(someType: .album(album))
                }
```

This worked fine for a single song.
Setting `player = nil` works if I start a song or album after a song but if I try to play an album when an album is currently playing I get the error: `"An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any useful resources to look at for understanding `AVQueuePlayer` but `AVAudioPlayer` can do the things I want to do anyways. Some parts in my code still need adjustment but here is what I came up with:

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

final class AudioQueueManager: ObservableObject {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false
    @Published var someType: SomeType = .album(Album.data)
    @Published var currentAlbumsong: AlbumSong = AlbumSong.data
    var currentTrack = 0
    var urls: [URL] = []
    var currentAlbum: Album = Album.data

    func startPlayer(someType: SomeType) {
        switch someType {
        case .song(let song):
            self.someType = .song(song)
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: song.track, withExtension: "mp3")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
                player?.play()
                isPlaying = true
            } catch {
                print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
            }
        case .album(let album):
            self.someType = .album(album)
            album.songs?.forEach({ albumsong in
                if urls.count < album.songs!.count {
                    urls.append(Bundle.main.url(forResource: albumsong.track, withExtension: "mp3")!)
                }
            })
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urls[currentTrack])
                currentAlbum = album
                currentAlbumsong = album.songs![currentTrack]
                player?.play()
                isPlaying = true
            } catch {
                print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func previousTrack() {
        if currentTrack - 1 < 0 {
            currentTrack = (urls.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (urls.count - 1)
        } else {
            currentTrack -= 1
        }
        playTrack()
    }

    func nextTrack() {
        if currentTrack + 1 > urls.count - 1 {
               currentTrack = 0
           } else {
               currentTrack += 1;
           }
           playTrack()
    }

    func playTrack() {
        if urls.count > 0 {
            player?.pause()
            player = nil
            player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urls[currentTrack])
            currentAlbumsong = currentAlbum.songs![currentTrack]
            player?.play()
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }
    
    func playPause() {
        guard let player = player else {
            print("Instance of audio player not found")
            return
        }
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.pause()
            isPlaying = false
        } else {
            player.play()
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        currentTrack = 0
        player = nil
        urls.removeAll()
        isPlaying = false
    }
}
```

Implementation still looks the same as above.